# Как прикрутить ReCaptha, если на form уже висит action

Tags: php, recaptcha

Есть попап плагин обратной связи, форме в котором уже присвоен экшн (отправка полей формы на email)

```
<div class="callback-form {$inline_container}">{$label}{$description}<form id="send"  class="clearfix callback-form-container" action="{$form_action}" method="POST"> //inputs <button id="" data-sitekey="" ...></button></from></div>
```

Прикрутил к форме recaptcha, пришлось изменить экшн с

```
$form_action = get_site_url() . '/?form_action=email';
```

на

```
$form_action = get_site_url() . '/captcha.php';
```

код reaptcha

```
<?php
require '1.php';
$recaptcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$object = new Recaptcha();
$response = $object->verifyResponse($recaptcha);
if(isset($response['success']) and $response['success'] != true) {
    exit("An Error Occured and Error code is :".$response['error-codes']);
}else {

}
```

Сейчас при отправке формы, естественно, открывается /captcha.php с текстом "Correct Recaptcha", на этом все заканчивается, email не уходит

Как мне сделать, чтобы после проверки капчи отправлялась форма, без переадресации на captcha.php

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Добавьте содержимое captcha.php в Ваш обработчик, зачем Вы отдельный создавали? А в момент, когда данные прошли Вашу валидацию И валидацию каптчи отправляйте письмо, сохраняйте в БД и т.д. Вам нужно объединить код просто.

Comment: @DaemonHK, спасибо. Я правильно понимаю, что require "captcha.php"; тут не отделаться? Просто  валидация проходит в JS, поэтому я пока не представляю, как интегрировать.

Comment: валидация в первую очередь должна идти от сервера. Вы можете аяксом получать ответ от гугл каптчи, проверять ответ на js и делать дальше валидацию на нем.

Comment: @DaemonHK, мне бы все же хотелось, чтобы проверка капчи проходила не по факту открытия формы, а по нажатию submit, т.е. после валидации. Но не получается заставить корректно работать. Если работает капча, то не работает валидация и наоборот. Ниже оставлю код, посмотрите, пожалуйста, если не трудно.

Answer (score 0):

валидация

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.callback-form-container').submit(function() {
            var formInputs = $(this).find('.validate');
            var errors = '';
            $(formInputs).each(function() {
                if($.trim(this.value) == '') {
                    fieldLabel = $(this).parent().find('span.label-text').html();
                    errors += '- ' + fieldLabel + '\n';
                }
            });
            if(errors.length > 0) {
                alert('Пожалуйста, заполните следующие поля:\n\n' + errors);
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                $('.submit-button').val('Пожалуйста, пододжите...');
                $('.submit-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                return true             
            }           
            });         
        }); 
});
```

reCaptcha.php

```
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
    $result = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=6(secret code)O&response=$_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]&remoteip=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]'), TRUE);

    if($result['success'] == 1) {
        console.log("Ok");

    } else {
        grecaptcha.reset();

    }
}
```

ajax, который не получается правильно разместить:

```
    function onSubmit(token) {                      
        document.getElementById("send").submit();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/reCaptcha.php",
        data: f.serialize(),
        dataType: "json",      
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Примерно как-то так:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var form=$('.callback-form-container');
    form.submit(function() {
        var formInputs = $(this).find('.validate');
        var errors = '';
        $(formInputs).each(function() {
            if($.trim(this.value) == '') {
                fieldLabel = $(this).parent().find('span.label-text').html();
                errors += '- ' + fieldLabel + '\n';
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/reCaptcha.php",
           data: form.serialize(),
           dataType: "json", 
           error:function(){
              //
           },
           success:function(result){
             if(errors.length > 0) {
                alert('Пожалуйста, заполните следующие поля:\n\n' + errors);
             }else{
                $('.submit-button').val('Пожалуйста, пододжите...');
                $('.submit-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                //еще какие-то действия            
             }
           }     
        });
    }); 
});
```

Общая суть: Валидируем данные, затем посылаем ajax-запрос на каптчу, если все ОК, то отправляем данные дальше, если нет, то показываем ошибки.

Comment: увы, результат аналогичный - проверка проходит, валидация нет, т.е. форму можно вообще не заполнять, она без проблем отправляется.

Comment: Вы должны еще проверять result от каптчи

Comment: добавил к error:function проверку (ниже опубликовал). Подскажите, а для чего это нужно? Проверка ведь есть и в captcha.php или это другое? У меня вопрос только на случай успешной проверки, если не нужны не какие сообщения, а просто продолжаем, то что нужно дописать? и что можно/нужно дописать, где вы обозначили "//еще какие-то действия" ,

Comment: Та, проверка, что Вы добавили в js, отвечает за валидацию формы, в каптче своя проверка, я бы вообще и Вашу запихал на серверную сторону, чтобы проверял сервер все сразу. Что за функция CheckSend?

Comment: извиняюсь, вместо checkSend должна быть beforeSend.  функция success тоже лишнюю добавил, вы уже прописали ее. К сожалению, так и не могу сделать, чтобы работала и валидация и капча. По поводу проверки, понимаю, что все лучше делать через сервер, но я этого не переделаю. Если еще есть что подсказать, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var form=$('.callback-form-container');
    form.submit(function() {
        var formInputs = $(this).find('.validate');
        var errors = '';
        $(formInputs).each(function() {
            if($.trim(this.value) == '') {
                fieldLabel = $(this).parent().find('span.label-text').html();
                errors += '- ' + fieldLabel + '\n';
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/reCaptcha.php",
           data: form.serialize(),
           dataType: "json", 
           CheckSend: function(){
                        $("#status").html("logging in...");
                    },
                    success: function(response){
                        $("#alert").html(response.text);
                        if(response.type=="success"){
                           //что добавить?            }
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        $("#alert").html("Failed.");           
           },
           success:function(result){
             if(errors.length > 0) {
                alert('Пожалуйста, заполните следующие поля:\n\n' + errors);
             }else{
                $('.submit-button').val('Пожалуйста, пододжите...');
                $('.submit-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                //еще какие-то действия            
             }
           }     
        });
    }); 
});
```